# Is an adjective with an intensifier an adjective phrase?

Tags: adjectives, phrases, adjective-phrases, intensifiers

> She is a **very beautiful** writer.

The bold part is a phrase.What kind of phrase it may be- a verb phrase, an infinitive phrase, a prepositional phrase or else?

Comment: The head word of the phrase is an adjective, so it must be an adjective phrase. Dependents of the head (complements, modifiers and determiners) are part of the phrase: the adverb "very" is a dependent (a modifier) of "beautiful" so it must be part of the AdjP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an adjective phrase, a group of words that describe the noun "writer".

Other examples of adjective phrases see [here](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/adjective-phrase-examples.html).

Comment: Very-intensifier , beautiful - adjective, writer-noun. In your link, **The movie was not too terribly long**, why not the adjective **long** included as a part of the adjective phrase?

Comment: Yes, it should be underlined too. No idea why it's not. By negligence, I suppose.